# MySQL delete query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, get, delete-row

I am sending values to a `PHP` form using the `GET` method. when I go to the `URL`, the link looks as follows:

```
http://www.url.com/getstuff.php?rid=sG94Ok5JtHQ&searcht=music&r=0
```

I am using the following function to handle the variables:

```
if (isset($_GET['rid'])) {

  if($_GET['r'] == 0) {
      echo $_GET['searcht']; 
      echo $_GET['rid'];
      mysql_query('DELETE FROM flags WHERE searchText = "'.$_GET['searcht'].'" AND videoID = "'.$rid.'"');
  } else
  {
      mysql_query('INSERT INTO removed (videoID) VALUES ("'.$_GET['rid'].'")');
      mysql_query('DELETE FROM flags WHERE searchText = "'.$_GET['searcht'].'" AND videoID = "'.$rid.'"');
  }
}
```

For some reason, the `INSERT` statement works above, but the `delete` statements do not do anything. When I `echo` `mysql_error()`, I am not getting anything either. I am sure the columns and table names are correct. Any help would be appreciated to help me get the delete statements working! Thanks!

Comment: You're not setting the value of `$rid` anywhere. Also, be VERY wary of possible SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Just a piece of advice, the `mysql` series of functions including query and connect have been deprecated. Instead use `mysqli` or `PDO`, as they are much more secure and in active development.

Comment: I am not sure but you mix ' and ". You start qry by ' and then close by " which make qry string not correct as mysql does not accept " for strings. So switch thrm and start with " and use ' to be passed in the qry. Echo qry is good debug. Then copy and execute on mysql and see result

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DELETE` query will succeed, even if nothing was deleted. In your code, you use the `$rid` variable, which is never set. There *is* a `$_GET['rid']` variable, so the fix is probably to either assign `$rid` to `$_GET['rid']`, e.g.

```
{
      $rid = $_GET['rid'];
      mysql_query('INSERT INTO removed (videoID) VALUES ("'.$_GET['rid'].'")');
      mysql_query('DELETE FROM flags WHERE searchText = "'.$_GET['searcht'].'" AND videoID = "'.$rid.'"');
}
```

Or to change all instances of `$rid` to `$_GET['rid']`, e.g.

```
{
      mysql_query('INSERT INTO removed (videoID) VALUES ("'.$_GET['rid'].'")');
      mysql_query('DELETE FROM flags WHERE searchText = "'.$_GET['searcht'].'" AND videoID = "'.$_GET['rid'].'"');
}
```

Also, the `mysql_` functions are deprecated, and you should use PDO/mysqli. Also, you don't sanitise your data anywhere (using `intval` or `mysql_real_escape_string` or similar), so you're quite open to SQL injection.

Comment: @user3630775 - whoops, I end up typing `$_POST[]` out of habit, since I rarely use `$_GET[]` variables. Yes, it should have been `$_GET['rid'];`

Answer (score -2):

Use `$_GET['rid']` in place of `$rid` in delete stmt

```
AND videoID = "'.$rid.'"');
```

Comment: This appears to have already been mentioned in a previous answer, and doesn't add additional information.